# C++ simple class declaration program

Tags: c++

I got a program to create in C++ in our introduction to C++ class in school. I am doing everything as I got in examples, but still getting errors.

w4x.cpp was given and I have to create Molecule.h and Molecule.cpp. I did that, but I am getting errors because my variables were not declared in scope, but I can't understand why.

```
// w4x.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "w4x.h"
#include "Molecule.h"

int main() {
    int n = MAX_MOLECULES;
    Molecule molecule[MAX_MOLECULES];

    cout << "Molecular Information\n";
    cout << "=====================" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MOLECULES; i++) {
        if (!molecule[i].read()) {
            n = i;
            i = MAX_MOLECULES;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Structure            Name                     Mass\n";
    cout << "==================================================" << endl; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        molecule[i].display();
}


//Molecule.h
const int MAX_STRUCT = 10;
const int MAX_NAME = 20;

class Molecule {
    char name[MAX_STRUCT];
    char rate[MAX_NAME];
    double weight;
public:
    Molecule();
    void read(const char*, const char*, double);
    void display() const;
    ~Molecule();
};


//Molecule.cpp     
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
#include "Molecule.h"

Molecule::Molecule(){
    name[0]= '\0';
    rate[0]= '\0';
    weight = 0;
}

void::read(const char* n, const char* r, double w) {
    weight = w;
    strncpy (name, n, MAX_STRUCT);
    name[MAX_STRUCT]='\0';
    strncpy (rate, r, MAX_NAME);
    rate[MAX_NAME]='\0';
    cout << "Enter structure : ";
    cin.getline (n, MAX_CHARS);
    cout << "Enter full name : ";
    cin.getline (r, MAX_NAME);
    cout << "Enter weight : ";
    cin >> w;
}

void::display() const
{
    int x;
    for ( x=0; x<i; x++)
        cout << n << "      " << r << "        " << w << endl;
}
```

My first question is, how can I pass `char name[MAX_STRUCT]; char rate[MAX_NAME]; double weight;` from Molecule.h to Molecule.cpp

Comment: if anyone can explain me concept of using classes in OOP by this example in simple words I would be very happy.

Comment: What part of the code is causing the compilation error?

Comment: You should avoid *using-directives*, and more so before including headers.

Comment: "but still getting errors."... "but i am getting errors because my variables were not declared in scope".  You must post the EXACT error message, including the line it refers to.

Comment: @JohnWalter You're calling `!molecule[i].read()` but not passing the arguments. Also, `read()` is defined as type `void` so it will not return anything to to the `if` statement.

Comment: My first question is, how can I pass char name[MAX_STRUCT];  char rate[MAX_NAME];  double weight; from Molecule.h to Molecule.cpp

Comment: @JohnWalter You don't pass data from one file to another. The `#include` directive will actually paste your header file inline with the source code when the preprocessor runs. You sound a little fuzzy on the concept of classes... I'd take a look at a [good tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson12.html)

Comment: alright, thanks for the link.

Comment: You have a problem with e.g. `name[MAX_STRUCT]='\0';`. This will write the terminating `'\0'` _one beyond_ the array! It should be name[MAX_STRUCT - 1]='\0';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your definitions is here:

```
void::read(const char* n, const char* r, double w)
```

and here

```
void::display() const
```

What `::` says *here*, is that you are implementing a function within a class. So you need to specify which class and which function! What you are telling it now, is that you are implementing a function inside class `void`, which is nonexistent.

You should convert them to:

```
void Molecule::read(const char* n, const char* r, double w)
void Molecule::display() const
```

---

Your other question regarding passing class members:

The functions of a class have access to its variables, therefore, you don't need to concern yourself with that. Just use the variables.

Also, if you notice in your `w4x.cpp`, the function `Molecule::read()` is called without parameters, so your TAs ask you to implement it without parameters. Indeed, since you have access to `Molecule::name`, `Molecule::rate` and `Molecule::weight` directly, you should read data and write to those variables instead of asking for parameters. Therefore, your read function would look like this:

```
void Molecule::read()
{
    // read into name, rate and weight
}
```

Furthermore, `w4x.cpp` expects `read` to report whether it has been successful or not. This means that you should do error checking in `Molecule::read` and return `0` if no errors or `-1` (for example) in case of errors.